# how to integrate Google MAP API in xamarin.forms project?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I followed these steps till now to integrate Google Map API:
1: I obtained the SHA-1
2: Created one project in google developer console
3: Obtained API Key by providing package name and SHA-1 key and restrict the key to mobile android app
4: Added necessary packages like xamarin.forms.map, xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps in to project
5: i added that key into android-manifest file as follow

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.webserviceappdemo">
    <application android:label="WebServiceAppDemo">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyB76kTIp0NbCsEXK_irDFG4NRpkK19YA1A"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Now you need to add the code to do whatever you want to with the Maps API.

Comment: when i build my project then i got the exception as  System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Android.Gms.Maps.MapView.get_Map' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Check this video. It's for Xamarin.Android but it's the same logic for Xamarin.Forms.

[Xamarin Android Tutorial - Google Maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Q0olRPsus&t=52s)